# How can I get the data of Tensorflow graphs

Tags: tensorflow, graph, resnet, vgg-net

I read some papers about graph partitioning and they used Tensorflow graphs such as VGG and ResNet.
I am wondering if these graph data are available or not? How can I access them.

Many thanks for any help

Comment: Can you link the papers? It's not very clear what you are asking for?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/intro_to_graphs shows you how to use graphs and advantages of Tensorflow graphs. Thanks!